# Unpack n dict with tuples as key in nxn matrix

Tags: python

I have a dict called GTY with 100 keys that are all combinations of

```
range(10,101,10)
```

(i.e. : (10,10), (10,20), ... (90,100), (100,100)).
I would like to "unpack" this dict and get a 10x10 matrix with 0 to 100 (with step 10) in columns and 0 to 100 ( with step 10) in rows.

I looked to do this by running a simple unpacking technique

```
np.array([GTY[i] for i in itertools.combinations(range(10,101,10), 2)])
```

but it yields data in a single column, not a 10x10 matrix. Is there an afficient a simple way to get a matrix with key-tuple nr1 in col and key-tuple nr2 in row ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 0 to 100 with step 10 will give a matrix of 11 x 11, not 10x10

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what your input and output look like? Could you add sample input and sampe output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

you could use numpy to generate an array of 11x11 and product to generate all combinations:

```
import numpy as np
z = itertools.product(range(0,101,10),repeat= 2)
z1 = np.array([i for i in z]).reshape(11,11,2)
for i in range(11):
    print(f'z[{i}] = {z1[i]}')
```

output:

z[0] = [[  0   0]
 [  0  10]
 [  0  20]
 [  0  30]
 [  0  40]
 [  0  50]
 [  0  60]
 [  0  70]
 [  0  80]
 [  0  90]
 [  0 100]]

z[1] = [[ 10   0]
 [ 10  10]
 [ 10  20]
 [ 10  30]
 [ 10  40]
 [ 10  50]
 [ 10  60]
 [ 10  70]
 [ 10  80]
 [ 10  90]
 [ 10 100]]

z[2] = [[ 20   0]
 [ 20  10]
 [ 20  20]
 [ 20  30]
 [ 20  40]
 [ 20  50]
 [ 20  60]
 [ 20  70]
 [ 20  80]
 [ 20  90]
 [ 20 100]]

z[3] = [[ 30   0]
 [ 30  10]
 [ 30  20]
 [ 30  30]
 [ 30  40]
 [ 30  50]
 [ 30  60]
 [ 30  70]
 [ 30  80]
 [ 30  90]
 [ 30 100]]

z[4] = [[ 40   0]
 [ 40  10]
 [ 40  20]
 [ 40  30]
 [ 40  40]
 [ 40  50]
 [ 40  60]
 [ 40  70]
 [ 40  80]
 [ 40  90]
 [ 40 100]]

z[5] = [[ 50   0]
 [ 50  10]
 [ 50  20]
 [ 50  30]
 [ 50  40]
 [ 50  50]
 [ 50  60]
 [ 50  70]
 [ 50  80]
 [ 50  90]
 [ 50 100]]

z[6] = [[ 60   0]
 [ 60  10]
 [ 60  20]
 [ 60  30]
 [ 60  40]
 [ 60  50]
 [ 60  60]
 [ 60  70]
 [ 60  80]
 [ 60  90]
 [ 60 100]]

z[7] = [[ 70   0]
 [ 70  10]
 [ 70  20]
 [ 70  30]
 [ 70  40]
 [ 70  50]
 [ 70  60]
 [ 70  70]
 [ 70  80]
 [ 70  90]
 [ 70 100]]

z[8] = [[ 80   0]
 [ 80  10]
 [ 80  20]
 [ 80  30]
 [ 80  40]
 [ 80  50]
 [ 80  60]
 [ 80  70]
 [ 80  80]
 [ 80  90]
 [ 80 100]]

z[9] = [[ 90   0]
 [ 90  10]
 [ 90  20]
 [ 90  30]
 [ 90  40]
 [ 90  50]
 [ 90  60]
 [ 90  70]
 [ 90  80]
 [ 90  90]
 [ 90 100]]

z[10] = [[100   0][100  10][100  20][100  30]
 [100  40]
 [100  50]
 [100  60]
 [100  70]
 [100  80]
 [100  90]
 [100 100]]